# how can I decrease the size of the final package of the Oracle MAF applications?

Tags: oracle, oracle-maf

i'm developing oracle MAF Applications for mobile devices. the initial size of the packages r about 20 MB..
the MAF architecture has a built-in lightweight JVM ([ORACLE MOBILE APPLICATION FRAMEWORK DATA SHEET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/maf/documentation/oraclemaf-datasheet-2220993.pdf)) for business logic...

can I choose which libraries should b exported in final package to decrease the size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to choose which libs should be exported.
The only thing you can do is deploy to production instead of debug (initial size is minimum 15mb).

Comment: is there any official documentation about this?

Comment: @Mahdi Details about deployment can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/mobile201/mobile/mobile-develop.htm (Choose Eclipse or JDeveloper)

Answer (score 1):

You should deploy in Release mode - for Android the instructions are here.

[Speed up ADF Mobile Deployment to Android with Keystore and "Release" Packaging](https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/speed_up_adf_mobile_deployment).